# Linux folder size limit

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, inode

We are using below code to create folder in Linux server.

```
File dir = new File(filePath);
            if(!dir.isDirectory())
             dir.mkdirs();
```

After that creating files inside that programatically and writing into it.

But the problem is after certain size new files are not getting created.(Even free space is there in the folder).

Is there any restriction for no. of file or folder size? Please let me know how to check.

Comment: which linux ? ubuntu ? redhat ? mint ? which programming language ? C ? Python ? (doesn't look like shell nor php).

Comment: First thing to check is whether all the inodes have been used up. Run `df -i` to check.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory

Answer (score 20):

There is a limit to the number of files that can be created in a partition, and in a directory.

I found the following information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466596/2715348).

## [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32):

- Maximum number of files: 268,173,300
- Maximum number of files per directory: 2<sup>16</sup> - 1 (65,535)
- Maximum file size: 2 GiB - 1 without [LFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support), 4 GiB - 1 with

## [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS):

- Maximum number of files: 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (4,294,967,295)
- Maximum file size

  - Implementation: 2<sup>44</sup> - 2<sup>6</sup> bytes (16 TiB - 64 KiB)
  - Theoretical: 2<sup>64</sup> - 2<sup>6</sup> bytes (16 EiB - 64 KiB)
- Maximum volume size

  - Implementation: 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 clusters (256 TiB - 64 KiB)
  - Theoretical: 2<sup>64</sup> - 1 clusters

## [ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2):

- Maximum number of files: 10<sup>18</sup>
- Maximum number of files per directory: ~1.3 × 10<sup>20</sup> (performance issues past 10,000)
- Maximum file size

  - 16 GiB (block size of 1 KiB)
  - 256 GiB (block size of 2 KiB)
  - 2 TiB (block size of 4 KiB)
  - 2 TiB (block size of 8 KiB)
- Maximum volume size

  - 4 TiB (block size of 1 KiB)
  - 8 TiB (block size of 2 KiB)
  - 16 TiB (block size of 4 KiB)
  - 32 TiB (block size of 8 KiB)

## [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3):

- Maximum number of files: min(volumeSize / 2<sup>13</sup>, numberOfBlocks)
- Maximum file size: *same as ext2*
- Maximum volume size: *same as ext2*

## [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4):

- Maximum number of files: 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (4,294,967,295)
- Maximum number of files per directory: unlimited
- Maximum file size: 2<sup>44</sup> - 1 bytes (16 TiB - 1)
- Maximum volume size: 2<sup>48</sup> - 1 bytes (256 TiB - 1)

Comment: `Maximum number of files per directory: ~1.3 × 10^20` is greater than `Maximum number of files: 10^18`, is this correct?

Comment: Maximum number of files per directory: ~1.3 × 10^20 is greater than Maximum number of files: 10^18, is this correct ... Why this strange behaviour?

Comment: This is actually not correct! These numbers are purely theoretical values, but in reality others factors will prevent you from saving millions of files inside a single folder (hash collision, inode limit, etc.). I learned that the hard way. Folder tree limit is 64k btw.

Comment: @Sliq yea I just had some long running processes keep dying because they would fill up directories with too many files.  I think that "Implementation defined limit" would be more appropriate than "unlimited" in this case...